# Was a teenager admitted to Stanford University after repeatedly writing #BlackLivesMatter on a supplemental essay?

Tags: united-states, university

This [source](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/muslim-teenager-ziad-ahmed-blacklivesmatter-stanford-application-100-times-repeat-university-a7665591.html#commentsDiv) claims that a teenager got accepted into Stanford University after writing #BlackLivesMatter, when answering a supplemental essay question,

> What matters to you, and why?

Is this true?

Comment: The current wording of the question implies that this one answer to one essay question was the sole deciding factor in his admittance.  Is anyone claiming that?

Comment: @jwodder I read it that such a thing would/should be a strong push toward non-admittance. That seems a more reasonable understanding.

Comment: His tweet is from April 2017. Common sense would say Stanford would've said something if it wasn't true.

Comment: Generally, not replying to fake news is better than denying it.

Comment: The article does not claim that this was an "answer to an essay question". It simply says that he wrote it on the application in answer to the question, not that an essay was expected.

Comment: @DJClayworth yes, it does "When Ziad Ahmed was asked on his Stanford University application 'What matters to you, and why?”, his answer was clear."  It is widely known that Stanford has such an essay question.  https://www.admitsee.com/blog/what-matters-to-you-and-why-stanford-supplemental-essay-examples ; https://www.apstudynotes.org/stanford/what-matters-to-you-and-why/

Comment: Sorry yes. I meant it was not an *academic* essay question.

Comment: @GEdgar claims of a “backfire effect” have recently been debunked.

Comment: Note that this essay was not the *only* reason he was admitted.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - not quite. It's more complicated than that (both the backfire effect claim AND the "debunking")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Stanford application instructions state](https://admission.stanford.edu/apply/freshman/essays.html):

> Freshman Application Requirements

...

> Stanford Short Essays
>
> Candidates respond to all three essay topics. There is a 100-word minimum and a 250-word maximum for each essay.
>
> 1.The Stanford community is deeply curious and driven to learn in and out of the classroom. Reflect on an idea or experience that makes you genuinely excited about learning.
>
> 2.Virtually all of Stanford's undergraduates live on campus. Write a note to your future roommate that reveals something about you or that will help your roommate—and us—know you better.
>
> 3.Tell us about something that is meaningful to you, and why?

NBC News [reported](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/teen-accepted-stanford-after-writing-blacklivesmatter-100-times-application-n742586):

> Stanford University confirmed Ahmed's acceptance to NBC News but declined to further discuss the student's application.

Answer (score 14):

**This story is reported by multiple reputable news stories, and we have no reason to doubt it.**

Reputable sources that report the story include [The Independent](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/world/americas/muslim-teenager-ziad-ahmed-blacklivesmatter-stanford-application-100-times-repeat-university-a7665591.html), [CNN](https://www.cnn.com/2017/04/05/us/stanford-application-black-lives-matter-trnd/index.html), [NBC](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/us-news/teen-accepted-stanford-after-writing-blacklivesmatter-100-times-application-n742586) and [Time](http://time.com/4728113/ziad-ahmed-stanford-black-lives-matter/). All the stories carry similar information.

Some things to note about this story:

- The question is not intended to show academic or any other kind of skills. It is a '[supplemental essay question](https://www.admitsee.com/blog/what-matters-to-you-and-why-stanford-supplemental-essay-examples)' which is 'designed for applicants to demonstrate their personality and passion', and has a 250 word limit.
- There is no indication that Ziad Ahmed was anything less than qualified because of the other details of his application. Ziad was also accepted to Yale and Princeton.

Comment: Well, as @DJClayworth's answer notes, this same story has been reported by multiple reputable sources. Pretty much all of them spend time going on about the strength of his activist credentials (intern for the O'Malley and Clinton campaigns, giving a TedxTalk, founding multiple organizations, acknowledged by Obama while in office, picture with Clinton). The "#BlackLivesMatter" wasn't posted just once, but rather 100 times, as the micro-essay had a minimum of 100 words. There might have been some question of whether he actually got in, or whether this was a fabricated stunt, but NBC says that S